# Keeping a PictureBox centered inside a container

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am designing a simple picture viewer with ability to do some basic image processing. At the moment I have the problem of keeping the `PictureBox` centered inside a `TabPage` all the time as well as keeping the picturebox width and size same as the picture its showing. So far I had no success.

I have the following code that I call in form constructor to position it in center. it works the first time to center the picturebox:

```
private void SetPictureBoxOriginalSizeAndLocation(bool makeImageNull = false, DockStyle dockStyle = DockStyle.None)
{
    if (makeImageNull) picBoxView.Image = null;
    picBoxView.Dock = dockStyle;

    var xPoint = tabImageView.Location.X + ((splitContainer.Panel2.Width / 2) / 2);
    var yPoint = tabImageView.Location.Y;

    var width = tabImageView.Width / 2;
    var height = (tabImageView.Height / 2) - toolStripImageView.Height;

    if (picBoxView.Image == null) return;

    //Resize image according to width
    picBoxView.Image = ImageMethods.ResizeImage(picBoxView.Image.Tag.ToString(), width, height, false); 

    picBoxView.Location = new Point(xPoint, yPoint);
    picBoxView.Width = width;
    picBoxView.Height = height;
}
```

But it does not resize the picturebox to its image (you can see the black part that is back color for the picturebox control):

[image: IT is ok the first time]

The problem is getting worse as soon as I resize the form, the picturebox position will goes to top:

[image: Form resized]

I call the code above in form's resize event as well, no idea why it works when application starts. Would be nice if someone can tell me what properties I should take care of to achieve a nicely centered picturebox which always is as big as its image.

Comment: Try to set Dock to fill and set the Image as background image. BackgroundImageLayout can be set to Center. And BackGroundColor to Transparent

Comment: Does the `picturebox.Image` size equalst to `picturebox` size? because I need to work on the pixels of the image, I dont know if the picturebox is larger than picture, the image I am working on will be the picturebox itself?! sounds stupid I know!

Comment: but then again I think I will have problem if I want to zoom in in the picture!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's pretty easy if you just set the `Anchor` style to none:

```
picBoxView = new PictureBox();
picBoxView.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
picBoxView.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
tabImageView.Controls.Add(picBoxView);
CenterPictureBox(picBoxView, myImage);
```

Then just center the `PictureBox` initially whenever you change the image of the `PictureBox`:

```
private void CenterPictureBox(PictureBox picBox, Bitmap picImage) {
  picBox.Image = picImage;
  picBox.Location = new Point((picBox.Parent.ClientSize.Width / 2) - (picImage.Width / 2),
                              (picBox.Parent.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (picImage.Height / 2));
  picBox.Refresh();
}
```

Having the `Anchor = None` will center the `PictureBox` control for you whenever the parent container gets resized because it "isn't" anchored to the default Left and Top locations.

Answer (score 1):

Givien a `Form` with `TabControl`, which has `Dock` set to `Fill`, below will keep your `PictureBox` in the centre. It also sets `PictureBox` size to `Bitmap` size:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(320, 200);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CenterTheBox();
        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CenterTheBox();
        }

        void CenterTheBox()
        {
            pictureBox1.Size = b.Size;
            var left = (tabPage1.ClientRectangle.Width - pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Width) / 2;
            var top = (tabPage1.ClientRectangle.Height - pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Height) / 2;
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(tabPage1.ClientRectangle.Location.X + left, tabPage1.ClientRectangle.Location.Y + top);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem lies here

```
var xPoint = tabImageView.Location.X + ((splitContainer.Panel2.Width / 2) / 2);
var yPoint = tabImageView.Location.Y;

var width = tabImageView.Width / 2;
var height = (tabImageView.Height / 2) - toolStripImageView.Height;
```

ypoint is alwways set to tabImageView Y, althought it should be set to

```
tabImageView.Location.Y + (tabImageView.Size.Height - picBoxView.Size.Height)/2
```

should be almost the same with xPoint

```
tabImageView.Location.X + (tabImageView.Size.Width - picBoxView.Size.Width)/2
```

and

```
width = picBoxView.Image.Width;
height = picBoxView.Image.Height;
```