# PictureBox scrollable?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Imagine that i have a Picturebox with 2000x2000 size and i only which to see 1000x1000 of that and scroll the rest, how can i do that?

I've tried with a picturebox inside a panel but without success.

The purpose of picturebox is to draw lines, grid, snap and stuff like the link bellow (is for a 2D structural analysis tool).

Something like this:
[Screenshot from Ftool software](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-T3h6qcBrrR0/URxIX796aPI/AAAAAAAAAZ4/iU7ZBOMoLYw/s1600/cg1.jpg)

Could someone help me?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Picture box should work inside the panel

Answer (score 2):

You didn't document why the PictureBox inside a Panel control didn't work, but here are the key properties to set when you have the PictureBox as a child control of the Panel:

```
Panel1.AutoScroll = True
PictureBox1.Location = Point.Empty
PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
PictureBox1.Image = yourImage
```

Comment: @EuricoCorreia There is nothing stopping you from posting a comment or editing your question to include more relevant information.  Why would my example not help you?

Comment: Perhaps i may not have explained well and i apologize for that.
I tried your solution but didn't work. What is happening to me is this http://imageshack.com/a/img538/1074/PMl30j.png
when i use the scrollbar he show me beyond picturebox and i don't want that, what i want is when i use the scrollbar, that must begin centerd, only show the picturebox and not beyond that. I think this is a position problem.

I have a panel 1169x551 and
a picturebox 2001x1001.

How can i do this?

Comment: I was editing my comment, because i accidentally pressed enter, but i exceed the 5 minutes lol

Comment: @EuricoCorreia See [Keeping a PictureBox centered inside a container](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9383029/719186).  Still not sure about your issue.  The screen shot doesn't help much since I don't know which control is the PictureBox and which is the Panel.  Looks like there are margin issues perhaps.  Your PictureBox is bigger than the Panel, so I don't know how my code doesn't fix your problem.  Do you have other controls or panels inside the panel, too?

Comment: Ok i'll try to explain better, i'm developing a 2D structural analysis program and the GUI is this http://imageshack.com/a/img673/5446/uwPYcK.png, the picturebox is the white-smoke one.
So, the picturebox total size is 2000x1000 px, which in the screenshot only 1169x551 px are visible. What i pretend is to be able to scroll the picturebox in order to see its total dimensions. Can you understand now @LarsTech?

Comment: @EuricoCorreia I don't understand why you don't put the PictureBox inside a Panel with the code I provided.  The panel provides the scrollbars.  The other way to do this is to replace your PictureBox with a double-buffered panel where you set the AutoScrollMinSize yourself.

Comment: can you provide me your email? i want to send you my project for better compression of the issue and to see if you can help me, and i'll delete this comment.