# C# centre picturebox inside form

Tags: c#

How can I centre picture box inside a form?

Isn't really much to show code wise as I'm just trying to figure out how to centre content

But I did try set x and y in respect to image size & form size, form size width is 400, image width is 300, so I assumed setting

```
x = 50
```

would center the image but didn't seem to center correctly, so maybe my maths is terrible?

Comment: Have you tried with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375588/keeping-a-picturebox-centered-inside-a-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Left` and `Top` property of your `PictureBox` inside the form constructor to :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - pictureBox1.Width) / 2;
    pictureBox1.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - pictureBox1.Height) / 2;
}
```

Comment: where can I place this code? I did it onclick and clearly it works on clicking the image, but where can I set picturebox properties programmatically

Comment: To keep it centered after resizing the form: Turning off all Anchors will keep it centered..